# Clio API: bulk actions not returning 303 status code

Tags: node.js, express, npm-request, clio-api

I'm not seeing a 303 response for bulk actions using latest v4 api for the `activities` endpoint.

From [The API Documentation:](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#tag/Bulk-Actions)

> 1. Make a request to the action with an X-BULK header with the value true. The response will always be a 202 Accepted.
> 2. Poll the URL provided in the Location header of the response. This URL is for the Bulk Actions endpoint.
> 3. Once the action is complete, polling the URL will return a 303 See Other response.
> 4. Download the response from URL in the Location header of the 303 See other response.

Here's what I'm doing:

I issue the initial request to the activities endpoint with the `X-BULK` header set to `'true'`.

- I receive a `202 Accepted`response with a `Location` header set to the polling url.

I begin polling the provided url from the `Location` header.

- I receive a few `200` responses with the following data and headers:

Data:

```
{"data":{"id":26952539,"etag":"\\"434fa52f83b8e0bb72677f60b8297866\\""}}
```

Headers:

```
{ 
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  status: '200 OK',
  'last-modified': 'Sat, 02 Dec 2017 22:17:13 GMT',
  'x-ratelimit-limit': '50',
  'x-ratelimit-reset': '1512253080',
  'x-ratelimit-remaining': '45',
  'x-request-id': '4674a764-c417-448c-af09-c6dae1cabe15',
  etag: '"434fa52f83b8e0bb72677f60b8297866"',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, private, no-store',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-api-version': '4.0.5',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  date: 'Sat, 02 Dec 2017 22:17:13 GMT',
  'set-cookie':
  [ 'XSRF-TOKEN=oQqTKV8XKRm9oiMuY1OFZ6qleZyRyvtcs9v52%2FWyeiVXxvVszHLiXsQkWelnUHs3ErSsH64ctIpehxErulAWHg%3D%3D; path=/; secure',
    '_session_id=7babc5f94bc48ecd5d18d4b40c17d6ca; path=/; secure; HttpOnly' ],
  server: 'nginx',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains' 
}
```

However a `303` never comes. After a few of the above `200`s I get another `200` with the payload:

Data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data": [ {id: 1...}, {id: 2...}, {id: 3...}, ... ],
      "status": 200
    }
  ],
  "status": "completed",
  "requested": 46,
  "performed": 46
}
```

Headers:

```
{ 
  'x-amz-id-2': '1uiNt20Vd/X74JxKZKrt/hah7aof8xfhZlt7fhlDt8b3G2nA47Y8ZDaohb2drSF8ErniirRK2Es=',
  'x-amz-request-id': '2B29557952779E29',
  date: 'Sat, 02 Dec 2017 22:17:15 GMT',
  'last-modified': 'Sat, 02 Dec 2017 22:17:14 GMT',
  'x-amz-expiration': 'expiry-date="Wed, 06 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="Expiration rule (auto-generated)"',
  etag: '"58e33e4eced83d145bf6dec9f72b97be-1"',
  'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256',
  'content-encoding': 'utf-8',
  'x-amz-version-id': '2Ou7F__59Pz8WKOKZwFg_fOuhQjD5ro0',
  'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="activities 20171202.json";',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '9593',
  server: 'AmazonS3',
  connection: 'close' 
}
```

It appears I can work around this sufficiently by testing for `status === 'completed'`, or even checking for the presence of the `content-disposition` header.

Am I doing something wrong that prohibits a `303` response, or are there semantics for the `activities` endpoint that I'm ignoring?

Is it sufficient to test for `status === 'completed'` to work around this issue?

Note: I am passing the `Authorization` header for every request, which includes the access token.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question to help reproduce the issue, which tool are you using ? cURL, Postman or a node.js API client?

Comment: @MatthewHoag, I'm using a node.js app with the Express framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the Clio API-V4.
The best solution at this time is:

testing the payload of the `200`  for status === 'completed'

We are working on resolving the lack of 303 response.  In the meantime we will update the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround I've been using with very good results:

1. Use the `ignore_redirect` parameter when querying a bulk action status:

   /api/v4/bulk_actions/?ignore_redirect=true
2. Use the `?fields=Response_Url` parameter to get the actual URL of the response.
3. Download the result from the `Response_Url` property.

I've never had these methods fail.